# How to add a custom Unicode character to texmaker

Tags: texmaker, unicode, editors

I downloaded latest version of TexMaker editor. As My main language is persian, I need Non Breaking Space character unicode (`U+00A0`). But TexMaker not type it with usual keys (`ctrl+shift+2` and `shift + space`).
But I can copy this character from another software and paste in TexMaker!
My question is how can I assign a shortcut key for this character.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to create a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‌‌‌I used `User Tags` in `User` menu to define a tag with Non-breaking space in the content. Now I can set Non-breaking Space Just via `Shift+F1` shortcut key. Just I wish I could change this shortcut key to `Shift+Space` To have same Experience with other editors :).